# How many torpedoes does it take to sink the Aircraft Carrier on Wake Island?

Tags: battlefield-1942

On the Wake Island Battlefield 1942 map, there is an Aircraft carrier and a battleship. On the Wake Island airbase there are three planes, two with bombs, and one with torpedoes. How many torpedoes does it take to sink the aircraft carrier?

Also, does the damage depend on angle of attack, ie dropping it into the water low and fast/dropping it onto the deck or is it the same for a hit anywhere?

[image]

Comment: It can be sunk? Really? Or am I mixing something up here?

Comment: *nod* I've seen before after a long pounding (and ramming with the destroyer) it sinks. Note the tag Battlefield 1942, not Battlefield 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it takes at least 8 torpedoes (launched from the plane, like above). I know BF1942 is a much older game but there's your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hits at right angles with bombs and torpedoes will cause more damage, yes.  Another effective strategy for taking out the carrier can be to deck bomb from high altitude whilst "looping the loop".